# Kramers-Kronigs relations of electrical conductivity for a translationally invariant system

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, electric-current

The spatio-temporal Fourier transform of electrical conductivity in a translationally invariant system reads

$\sigma_{\alpha\beta}(\mathbf{q},\omega) = \frac{\text{i}}{\omega}\left[\frac{e^2\text{n}_e}{m}\delta_{\alpha\beta}+\frac{1}{\hbar}\Pi^{R}(\mathbf{q},\omega)\right]$

where $\langle n(\mathbf{r})\rangle_{0} =  \text{n}_e$ is electron density averaged over the entire sample ( i.e just a constant).We have

$\text{Re} \ \sigma_{\alpha\beta}(\mathbf{q},\omega) = - \frac{1}{\hbar \omega} \text{Im} \ \Pi^{R}(\mathbf{q},\omega)$

$\text{Im} \ \sigma_{\alpha\beta}(\mathbf{q},\omega) = \frac{e^2\text{n}_e}{m\omega}\delta_{\alpha\beta} + \frac{1}{\hbar \omega} \text{Re} \ \Pi^{R}(\mathbf{q},\omega)$

Now, the Kramers-Kronig relations give

$\begin{eqnarray}
\text{Im} \ \sigma_{\alpha\beta}\left(\mathbf{q},\omega\right)  & = &  -\frac{2\omega}{\pi} \ \text{P} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ \text{Re} \ \sigma_{\alpha\beta}\left(\mathbf{q},\nu\right)}{\nu^2-\omega^2}d\nu \\
  & = &  -\frac{2\omega}{\pi} \ \text{P} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{-\frac{1}{\hbar\nu}\text{Im} \ \Pi^{R}_{\alpha\beta}(\mathbf{q},\nu)}{\nu^2-\omega^2}d\nu \\
  & = &  \frac{2\omega}{\pi}\frac{1}{\hbar} \ \text{P} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\text{Im} \ \Pi^{R}_{\alpha\beta}(\mathbf{q},\nu)}{\nu\left(\nu^2-\omega^2\right)}d\nu \\
  & = &  \frac{2\omega}{\pi}\frac{1}{\hbar} \ \text{P} \int_{0}^{\infty}\text{Im} \ \Pi^{R}_{\alpha\beta}(\mathbf{q},\nu)\left( \frac{1}{2\omega^2\left(\nu-\omega\right)} + \frac{1}{2\omega^2\left(\nu+\omega\right)} - \frac{1}{\omega^2\nu} \right)d\nu \\
  & = &  - \frac{2\omega}{\pi}\frac{1}{\hbar} \ \text{P} \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\text{Im} \ \Pi^{R}_{\alpha\beta}(\mathbf{q},\nu)}{\omega^2\nu}d\nu+\frac{2\omega}{\pi}\frac{1}{\hbar} \ \text{P} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2\nu \ \text{Im} \ \Pi^{R}_{\alpha\beta}(\mathbf{q},\nu)}{2\omega^2\left(\nu^2-\omega^2\right)} d\nu \\
  & = &   -\frac{1}{\hbar\omega}\frac{2}{\pi} \ \text{P} \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\nu\text{Im} \ \Pi^{R}_{\alpha\beta}(\mathbf{q},\nu)}{\nu^2-0}d\nu+\frac{1}{\hbar\omega}\frac{2}{\pi} \ \text{P} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\nu \ \text{Im} \ \Pi^{R}_{\alpha\beta}(\mathbf{q},\nu)}{\left(\nu^2-\omega^2\right)} d\nu \\
  & = &  \frac{1}{\hbar\omega} \ \text{Re} \ \Pi^{R}_{\alpha\beta}(\mathbf{q},0)  +\frac{1}{\hbar\omega} \text{Re} \ \Pi^{R}_{\alpha\beta}(\mathbf{q},\omega)
\end{eqnarray}$

But this gives a contradiction because $\text{Re} \ \Pi^{R}_{\alpha\beta}(\mathbf{q},0) \neq \text{n}_e$.

Where is the mistake? Thank you very much

Comment: I haven't gone through the algebra in detail, but the Kramers-Kronig relations work if the susceptibility is analytic in the (closed) upper-half plane. Try replacing $\omega$ in the denominator with $\omega +i \delta$, where $\delta$ is a small positive number,

Comment: Yes,this is another way of doing it. It depends on how you define you initial interaction term.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The form of the Kramers-Kronig relation you used,
\begin{equation}
\text{Im} \ \sigma_{\alpha\beta}\left(\mathbf{q},\omega\right)   =   -\frac{2\omega}{\pi} \ \text{P} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ \text{Re} \ \sigma_{\alpha\beta}\left(\mathbf{q},\nu\right)}{\nu^2-\omega^2}d\nu,
\end{equation}
is true for a complex function which is (1) analytic in the upper-half plane, (2) satisfies $\text{Im} \ \sigma_{\alpha\beta}\left(\mathbf{q},-\omega\right) = - \text{Im} \ \sigma_{\alpha\beta}\left(\mathbf{q},\omega\right)$, and (3) decays sufficiently fast for large $|\omega|$. The first two properties imply
\begin{equation}
\text{Im} \ \sigma_{\alpha\beta}\left(\mathbf{q},0\right) = 0.
\end{equation}
So for the function $\sigma_{\alpha\beta}\left(\mathbf{q},\omega\right)$ you initially specified, this leads to
\begin{equation}
\text{Re} \ \Pi^{R}_{\alpha\beta}(\mathbf{q},0) = - \frac{ \hbar \text{n}_e}{m^2} \delta_{\alpha \beta},
\end{equation}
perfectly consistent with your manipulations. (You also missed a minus sign in your very last equality, but I assume this isn't what got you stuck.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate it